# How to create dynamic path using php variable?

Tags: php

I want to create a path with dynamic variable.

```
echo $path='App\Widgets\mywidgetname';
```

I want to replace `mywidgetname` then I have to put a variable like this

```
$path='App\Widgets\'.$widgetname; // (but this not working)
```

Comment: _but this not working_ Exactly how is it not working please. _but this not working_ is not much help to us. What does it do or what does it not do

Comment: First suggestion: `$path='App/Widgets/'.$widgetname;`

Comment: actually i want to use this laravel function to call a method of another controller app('App\Widgets\News')->config();

Comment: @Rummaan Check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$path = 'App\Widgets\mywidgetname';
$path = str_replace('mywidgetname', $widgetname, $path);
```

**OR**

```
$path = 'App\Widgets\mywidgetname';
$path = substr($path, 0, strrpos($path, "\\") + 1) . $widgetname;
```

Comment: Wow! Hammer to crack a nut

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
$path = sprintf("App\Widgets\%s", $widgetname);
echo $path;
```